# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions on port 80

Tags: sockets, websocket, windows-server-2012

I have my own web site hosted on a dedicated server. I have 2 IP addresses set up.

One is for my web server and the other is for my web socket.

I did this so that my web socket clients can access my server using port 80.

However, when I run my server application I get the error:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Now if I switch it to a different port it works (which I have allowed through the firewall). There is nothing entered in the Windows Logs.

I am running as an Administrator. I am using Windows server 2012.

Is there anything I can check?

I checked using netstat etc but this IP address is not being used on port 80 anywhere else

I have 2 IP addresses pointing to my server hosted at FastHosts.
So I have a web site (using IIS)

Originally I had a web socket connection/listener listing on port 8090.
I had created a rule in my firewall settings to allow access to this connection.

Indeed for over a year now I have been using this connection using port 8090.

It occurred to me last week that using a clients PC that they could not access the socket over port 8090. I assumed because of firewall issues.
So, I figured if i switched to port 80 for this socket it will not need an exception to that clients firewall rules.

The trouble is I cannot have a web server listening on port 80 and a web socket so I purchased another IP address from my host and 'added' to my network adapter.

I have made sure nothing else is using port 80 for this new IP address. But I get the access denied

As a test I created a default.html page which said 'hi' all with no issues.  I then 'stopped' the web server for that IP address

Comment: @RyanVincent Hi, sorry for my lack of clarity i will try and improve my question. thanks for posting

Comment: @RyanVincent I completely agree with I appreciate your time. doing this sort of thing is new to me so may (am!) asking things in a confused manner. I have edited my question and stand ready to imporove upon it :)

Comment: @RyanVincent yes, 1st thing i did was create a default.html page which said 'hi' all with no issues.  I then 'stopped' the web server for that ip address

Comment: Please add that to the question - it is useful. As now it is just the websocket server to sort out.

Comment: @RyanVincent OK - will do so. Good point!

Comment: @RyanVincent Hi, I have added to end of my question but can move it nearer to the start if you think be better there. Yes, everything you stated is correct.  This why I am flummoxed.  Also, I have no issues on 'pendant' questions/statements

Comment: @RyanVincent Ah, i see i will need to install. Also, my missus wants me stop as I am supposed to be taking her out for dinner :) I will have to come back to this tomorrow and pray you are still around :)

Comment: cool will do so - thanks :)

Comment: FYI, it is possible to write a single server that receives both web requests and webSocket requests on the same IP address on port 80.  webSockets were specially designed for this to be possible and it works this way because all webSocket requests start with an http request that just has a couple special headers in it.  You don't need two IP addresses and two server processes.

Comment: @jfriend00 hi that in way is depressing to hear as I only just purchased the IP address lol. When I get back I shall see if I can make it work on same IP address thanks :)